# How to validate the initialization of a const member variable before assigning it in C++

Tags: c++, validation, constructor, constants, member

Let's say I have this simple class with a const int member variable:

```
class MyClass{
    public:
        Myclass(int x, int y);
    private:
        const int importantNumber;
        int anotherNumber;
};

MyClass::MyClass(int x, int y) :importantNumber{x}
{
    this->anotherNumber = y;
}
```

Since `int importantNumber` is const, I can only set it during the creation of the object by the constructor (with a member initialization list, as seen above).

Now, the question: how could I possibly add validation for argument x given to the constructor before actually creating importantNumber with that value? Is it possible to create a `static int MyClass::validation(int a)` and use it on the member initialization list of the constructor like `importantNumber{validation(x)}`?

Even if it's possible, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you can separate validation logic and processing logic. Something along lines "if validator allows parameters, create object and process it, otherwise handle invalid data".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just add it.

```
MyClass::MyClass(int x, int y) : importantNumber{validate(x)}
{
    this->anotherNumber = y;
}
```

The `int validate(int original)` function can now return something other than `x` or throw an exception or `assert` or ask the user for confirmation, whichever you deem appropriate.

If it is just a simple check and you don't want to write a `validate` function you can use a lambda:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int x, int y) :importantNumber{
    [](int number){
        assert(number > 0);
        return number;
    }(x)}
{
    this->anotherNumber = y;
}
```

Although this can get a bit convoluted if you overdo it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary operator `condition ? true : false` in the constructor if you want to validate with a simple condition:

```
class MyClass{
    public:
        MyClass(int x, int y);
    private:
        const int importantNumber;
        int anotherNumber;
};

MyClass::MyClass(int x, int y) : importantNumber(x > 0 ? x : 0)
{
    this->anotherNumber = y;
}
```

However, be warned that things can quickly become difficult to read if you overdo it with this operator.

For something more complex, you could do something like this:

```
int validateIntegral(int x) const
{
    // Do validation on 'x'...

    return x;
}

class MyClass{
    public:
        MyClass(int x, int y);
    private:
        const int importantNumber;
        int anotherNumber;
};

MyClass::MyClass(int x, int y) : importantNumber(validateIntegral(x))
{
    this->anotherNumber = y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use factory function for creating a class instead of constructor.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  static MyClass* create (int x, int y);

private:
  MyClass(int x, int y);

private:
  const int importantNumber;
  int anotherNumber;
};

MyClass* MyClass::create (int x, int y)
{
  return x > 0 ? new MyClass(x, y) : NULL;
}
```

When you need some advanced validation of parameters, factories have following advantages:

- They avoid creation of object in memory if tests fail
- They have more flexibility over checking parameters in initialization 
  list
- You can return **NULL** if you dont need exceptions nor you want to have some ".is_valid()" member function for your class.

Comment: Thank you! Was unsure about that, changed from ref to pointer now; anyway it doesn't affect the logic.

Comment: Now you have unclear ownership semantics and unnecessary dynamic allocation. Returning by value / throwing an exception would be better, wouldn't it?

Comment: In general if class is not designed to support moving operations (e.g. we use old C++ standard without support for movement), passing it by value is a bad idea.

Comment: Dont get me wrong, I dont argue for pointer vs value, it is completely out of topic. I agree about your arguments on ownership. It is possible to use smart pointers just in case, but I think, they would make my example over-complicated for this particular answer.

Comment: On the contrary, returning by value has always been the recommended approach. Compilers have been eliding unnecessary copies of returned values for many years, long before it became mandatory in C++17 and long before they became moveable in C++11.

Comment: @grapes: See [copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).

Comment: Agree on that, thanks @notanalien. Leveraged today my c++.